# Run once on Spring Boot startup

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

What is the best alternative to `ContextRefreshedEvent` if it must be guaranteed that a method should be executed exactly once on the startup of a Spring Boot application?

```
@EventListener
public void myMethod(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Why, specifically, do you need an alternative, and have you tried `CommandLineRunner`?

Comment: What kind of operation do you want to run on the startup? database initialization, remote notification, pre-configure some bean, load local files, etc

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to run something at application startup.
These include:
`@Postconstruct` on a bean,
implement the `InitializingBean` interface,
implement the `ApplicationListener` interface,
and others.

Here is a link to a [Baeldung article that discusses this topic](https://www.baeldung.com/running-setup-logic-on-startup-in-spring).

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways, but a simple approach I usualy take is  you can use @PostConstruct on a singleton component method (or add it to its constructor)

```
@Component
public class MyComponent{
    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize(){
         //do something here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could declare a (singleton) bean and call your code from within the constructor. That won't give you much control over the timing, though.